# Laravel relation null on updated observer of model

Tags: laravel

I have a belongsToMany Relation, and I want update this relation, when parent model is updated. I have a code:

```
    protected static function boot()
    {
    parent::boot();

    /**
     * After model is created, or whatever action, clear cache.
     */
    static::updated(function ($model) {
        if($model->amount <= 0) {
            $model->products()->detach();
        } else {
            $product = $model->products->first();

            $model->products()->detach();

            for($i = 1; $i <= $model->amount; $i++) {
                $product->pachets()->attach($model->id, [
                    'product_id' => $product->id
                ]);
            }
        }

        Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    });
 }
```

I get null on `$product->pachets()` and error `Call to a member function pachets() on null`. If I have one or more products in pachet, then working good.

In Product model I have relation:

```
public function pachets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Pachet::class, 'pachet_products');
}
```

Comment: Do you have relations pachets in your Product model?

Comment: @mrakodol yes I have

Comment: Did you try $model->products()->sync(); instad of detach then attach ?

Comment: Yes, but that's not a problem, Problem in error: Call to a member function pachets() on null

Comment: maybe you have your FK in the wrong order. Try return $this->belongsToMany(Pachet::class, 'pachet_products', 'pachet_id', 'product_id');

Comment: `$model->products->first();`  can return `null`